# How to display data based on the user input in combo box wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

i have a combo box where user can type input and it will display the corresponding values based on the selection, but if user type any character like "C" by default it was displaying the first matching word "CAR" and the relevant data in other fields.

if user changes the input data was not clearing in other fields.

if user types values other then the values existing in the drop down still it shows the values that are previously populated and it was not clearing at all.

i want to autocomplete the combo box based on user input so that user can select from the drop down and if user types any value which are not in the drop down all the auto populated need to be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the below changes in the xaml it works fine

TextSearch.Text="{Binding usertext}" Text="{Binding ticketText}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsTicketEnable}" ItemsSource="{Binding LstTicket}" DisplayMemberPath="ticket" ValuePath="ticket" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicket}" TextChanged="cmbTicket_TextChanged"SelectedItemChanged="cmbTicket_SelectedItemChanged"

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand like you can use lostfocus event on Text Property rather than SelectedItem

```
 <ComboBox KeyUp="cmbDevice_KeyUp" IsEditable="True" x:Name="cmbDevice" TextSearchEnabled="True" Text="{Binding SelectedDevice,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList }">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ComboBox>
 private void cmbDevice_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbDevice.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
```